# Программа для решения нелинейного уравнения

Tags: java

**Задача**: написать программу, которая будет решать нелинейное уравнение методом [бисекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0). Известно, что корень уравнения находится на промежутке от [0; 10] и он только один. Точность по *Х* дожна быть не меньше, чем 0.001. В решении использовать рекурсию и указанный выше метод бисекции.

**Вопрос:**
Ниже программа, которая решает уравнение, указанное в методе *func*. В ее работе я понимаю все шаги кроме

```
if (end - start <= 0.001) return start;
```

Исходный код:

```
    public static double func(double x){
        return Math.cos(Math.pow(x, 5)) + Math.pow(x, 4) - 345.3 * x - 23;
    }

    // решить уравнение
    public static double  solve(double start, double end){
        if(end - start <= 0.001){
            return start;
        }

        double x = start + (end - start) / 2;

        if(func(start) * func(x) > 0){
            return solve(x, end);
        } else {
            return solve(start, x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve(0, 10)); 
    }
```

Заранее, спасибо

Comment: Если корень находится в отрезке, длина которого <= 0.001, то взяв одну из границ мы получим как раз его с точностью 0.001. Строго:  если x in [a; b], b - a <= eps, x0 = a, тогда |x0 - x| <= eps. В вашем случае eps = 0.001

Comment: @EzikBro спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная строка и обеспечивает точность в 0.001. Как я понял, end и start - промежуток в котором лежит корень уравнения, и если между ними менее 0.001, то останавливается расчёт,т.к. он отвечает заданному условию.